# Example of Artinian local ring over a field that is not finitely-dimensional

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ be an Artinian local ring over a field $k$. All the examples I know are finite-dimensional over $k$, like $k[x]/(x^n)$. Is it true in general?

**Update.** Well, $A$ probably should be finitely-generated, because it is a quotient of a local ring of a variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the modified question is affirmative: The residue field $K:=A/{\mathfrak m}$ of $A$ is a finitely generated, hence finite field extension of $k$, and the finitely many non-zero filtration quotients ${\mathfrak m}^l/{\mathfrak m}^{l+1}$ are of finite dimension over $K$, hence also over $k$.

Comment: Well said, Hanno: +1.

Answer (score 1):

No: $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb C$
(This answers the original question, which didn't mention finite generation.  Hanno has perfectly answered the modified question)